# Text formatting of lists in Pandoc's Markdown

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown, pandoc, cpu-word

I've added asterisks and a new line break to the sampleList elements in order to create a bulleted list format:

```
sampleList <- list(1, 2, 3)

# Create bulleted list
createPoints = function(list) {
  # Pre-allocate list
  setList <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(list))

  # Add elements to each line
  for (i in seq_along(list)) {
    line = sprintf("* %s  \n", list[[i]])
    setList[[i]] <- line
  }
  
  return(setList)
}

finalList = createPoints(sampleList)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "* 1  \n"

[[2]]
[1] "* 2  \n"

[[3]]
[1] "* 3  \n"
```

How do I print the individual elements in a bulleted sublist?

This does not work:

- Bullet 1

  - `r finalList`

My output comes with extra commas and no bullets for the sublists:

- Bullet 1

  - 1

  , * 2

  , * 3

**I would like it to look like this:**

- Bullet 1

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3

Comment: you could install `pander` instead and use it ie `pander::pander(sampleList)`

Answer (score 1):

Unlist your `finalList` object and collapse all elements together to avoid commas

```
sampleList <- list(1, 2, 3)

# Create bulleted list
createPoints = function(list) {
  # Pre-allocate list
  setList <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(list))

  # Add elements to each line
  for (i in seq_along(list)) {
    line = sprintf("* %s  \n", list[[i]])
    setList[[i]] <- line
  }
  
  return(setList)
}

finalList = unlist(createPoints(sampleList))
```

`r paste(finalList, collapse = " ")`

Comment: Any feedback about my answer @SRL

Comment: This was helpful, thanks! I had to adjust the sprintf to have two spaces in front of the asterisk in order to indent properly.